# In Google Maps is there a way to show a Box Info fixed in a corner?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem.
My current php project provides a Google Map at the users.
This map is managed by a javascript Script.

Now the problem: i need to insert in this map like an Infobox that contains informations about the map.
This box must be fixed in the corner, and not attacched in some point of the map.

But n the v3 APIs i dont see anything to make this.

Is possible with these APIs?

Thank you all.

Comment: I guess you can modify its position using CSS. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Controls** piece of the [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) to create your info box and add it to the map. See the [custom controls sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom) for an example. You can put whatever content you want in a div, and then place it on the map in one of the [ControlPosition](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#ControlPosition) types.